# Multiplication of Two Matrices

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, list-comprehension

I would like to ask about how to multiply two matrices. 
I have the Matrix mat1 `'((1 2) (4 5))` and mat2 `'((3 6) (7 8))`. I just have implemented this code:

```
(defun multi_matrices (mat1 mat2)
    (cond((or (null mat1) (null mat2)) nil)
         ((not(eq (length mat1) (length mat2))) nil)
         (( format t "~a" (mapcar #'* (car mat1) (car mat2))))
         ((cdr mat1)(multi_matrices (cdr mat1) (cdr mat2)) (print 'OK))))
```

but i get this:

```
(multi_matrices '((1 2) (4 5)) '((3 6) (7 8)))

               (3 12)(28 40)
```

That part is OK, but then I don't know how to sum the elements like the multiplication require: this link show  [how to multiply matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qe4N.jpg)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should make sure that every clause of COND begins with a USEFUL boolean expression. (FORMAT ...). is not a useful boolean expression. Also use = to compare numbers for numeric equality, not EQ.

Comment: You might also want to decide which Lisp dialect you are using. Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp are different languages.

Comment: It *looks* like emacs lisp, but I'm not too familiar with common lisp

Comment: @zv_: the FORMAT and MAPCAR looks like Common Lisp. MAPCAR in Emacs Lisp does not take more than one list.

Comment: I'm using LispBox(common lisp and Emacs+Slime)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CL-USER> (defun mmat (mat1 mat2)
           "multiply two matrices as lists of lists"
           (loop with num-rows1 = (length mat1)
              for row1 in mat1
              collect (loop for c from 0 below num-rows1
                         collect (loop for e in row1
                                    for r from 0
                                    sum (* e (nth c (nth r mat2)))))))
MMAT
CL-USER> (mmat '((1 2 3)(4 5 6)) '((7 8)(9 10)(11 12)))
((58 64) (139 154))
```

The function does not check if the input is correct.

Comment: If you use Emacs, I recommend the `slime-cl-indent` contrib.  Do `(add-to-list 'slime-contribs 'slime-cl-indent)` before `(slime-setup)` in your Emacs configuration.  It will indent `loop` much nicer.

Comment: Nice suggestion @Svante. Thanks!

Comment: TXR Lisp: `[maprod (op apply + [mapcar * @1 @2]) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) (transpose '((7 8) (9 10) (11 12)))]`. Result: flat list of dot-products, unfortunately: `(58 64 139 154)`.  `tuples` will reshape that, though. :)

Comment: @Kaz, very nice, indeed!